# Swagger: How to annotate object mapped to string

Tags: java, swagger

I am using a custom ObjectMapper to map a class to a String for Json Serialization & Deserialization

```
    module.addDeserializer(MonthUtil.class, new MonthUtilDeserializer());
    module.addSerializer(MonthUtil.class, new MonthUtilSerializer());
```

Another class used by the REST API contains a field and getter of type `MonthUtil`. In the Swagger definition, that field gets class `MonthUtil`, although the serialized object contains a string.

How can I annotate the class, or if need be the field or getter to tell swagger that this is effectively a string?
I tried adding `@ApiParam(type = "string")` to the field and the getter, but that didn't help.
I would prefer to annotate the class as being represented by a string.

Comment: You mean api response is a string?

Comment: Yes, the object is transmitted as string in the API. In the generated swagger.json, the definition of an object containing a month is `"$ref": "#/definitions/MonthUtil"`, but I need it to by `"type" : "string"`

Comment: MonthUtil is your response or another class which contains MonthUtil..you should show the structure and your api method.